# how to get a specific value of a column in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want all rows whose their value in column `col1` is equal to `yes`. in pandas I can get like this

```
df[df['col1']=='yes']
```

how is it in pyspark?

Comment: PySpark supports Pandas operators, as well, as of Spark 3.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [filter](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.filter.html) method from the DataFrame.

```py
df.filter(df["col1"] == "yes")
```

or

```py
df.filter("col1 == 'yes'")
```